# oracle database :: list users that you created and not system created

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I did some research on my own question and found this other exchange forum on databases:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48158/oracle-list-user-created-tables-in-the-sys-schema

It seems that trying to query that you yourself created is difficult to do, it seems you can't separate the system generated tables from your own.
Except via specifying a date.

I am using Oracle 11g Express version. I am just curious if things have changed and now its possible to do some better query so you do not see system tables displayed in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes things have got better. In 12c Oracle added a column, `ORACLE_MAINTAINED`, to the `%_USERS` views. This is a flag column, with 'Y' indicating that the account is maintained by an Oracle script such as `catalog.sql`. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DDD25C8F-7EC9-46BC-ABEA-529C64FA09E2.htm#REFRN20302).

The main purpose of the flag is to warn off DBAs from fiddling with Oracle-maintained users. We can also join `ALL_USERS.ORACLE_MAINTAINED` to `ALL_TABLES.OWNER` to filter system tables.

However, that's not quite the problem raised by the question to which you linked. There is still no way to winnow application-maintained tables from Oracle-maintained tables in a single schema.